# How to obtain the max value of a plot in JULIA?

Tags: plot, max, julia, plotly

I've been working on a proyect and I have to obtain the max value of a plot that I made in PlotlyJS, I need to obtain the frequency of a .wav file and print the musical note associated to that frequency. 
http://samcarcagno.altervista.org/blog/basic-sound-processing-julia/
I have been following this post but this only gave you the spectrogram of the frequency. To obtain the fundamental frequency I changed the value of y.

```
plot(scatter(;x=freqArray/1000, y=p),
Layout(xaxis_title="Frecuencia (kHz)",
        xaxis_zeroline=false,
        xaxis_showline=true,
        xaxis_mirror=true,
        yaxis_title="Intensidad (dB)",
        yaxis_zeroline=false,
        yaxis_showline=true,
        yaxis_mirror=true))
```

[That's the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoioN.png)
Please help me, I don't know how to obtain the frequency

Comment: `maximum(freqArray)` do not help?

Comment: It does not make sense to talk about the maximum value of a plot. What you need is the maximum value of the data that you put into the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You have two coupled vectors.  `p` contains the value of the intensities, and `freqArray` contains the matching frequencies. Your plot is displaying a sequence of `(x,y)` points defined by `(freqArray[i],p[i])` for all indices `i`.

You can use `indmax(p)` to return the index at which `p` has the maximal value. Then you can look up what the frequency is by indexing into `freqArray` at that index.

```
julia> p = rand(200);
       freqArray = 5:5:1000;

julia> idx = indmax(p)
114

julia> p[idx] # this is the maximum value
0.9968329198539723

julia> freqArray[idx] # and this is its frequency
570
```